# How do determine visible DOM elements within a scrolling DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, scroll

I have a DIV that I want to scroll the contents of. As the user scrolls (using either a custom scrollbar or scroll up/down buttons), I need to know what DOM elements are visible within the scrollable DIV. I'd be happy to know even just one DOM element, as I can use that to walk the DOM and find a particular parent element that I'm looking for.

Are there any plugins that provide this kind of information in the scroll completion event, or can someone recommend a way of doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Checkout [Waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints) and/or [jquery scrollspy](https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy).  These do exactly the functionality you are looking for.